# Number of neurons for LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

### There are 5 input features indicated by true/false and independent of each other

train_X = [[TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,FALSE]]

train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))

### Expected output 5 true/false output independent of each other

[[TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,FALSE]]

### Is below the correct way to define model for training? Input 5, Output 5?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])   ))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: It's quite pointless to use a LSTM if you don't have a "sequence". Better to use just dense layers and shapes (batch, 5).

Comment: @DanielMöller the previous [[TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,FALSE]] produce the next [[TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,FALSE]] . It has sequence

Comment: Ok.... and what about the way you want it to work?? Could you please detail the sequential process you want your model to follow? Examples: Do you want to input many steps and produce one step? Do you want to input only one step and produce the next step? Do you want to continuously produce one step, make this step become an input and get a another step? Do you want to input an entire sequence and output a parallel entire sequence? Etc....

Comment: @DanielMoller, exactly .just continuously one step produce next step. [x1] produce [x2], [x2] produce [x3] , x[3] produce [x4] in sequence. No shuffling. The shape of input/output is the same (5,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(any, stateful = True, input_shape=(1, 5) ))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

When going step by step, your input shape, which is `(batch, steps, features)` should consider only one step. (Batch is ignored when you define input shape in layers).

The `stateful=True` is necessary because you will want the model to consider that every batch you provide is still the same sequence, not a new sequence.

The `sigmoid` activation is the one with minimum = 0 and maximum = 1 (ideal for true/false).

Only the input and the output must have 5 features. The internal layers can have whatever size you want.